# How can I decode minifieed javascript code stack

Tags: javascript, source-maps

If i have the sourcemap file, is there a tool for me to decode minified javascript code stack? I understand Chrome Dev Tool can import the sourcemap for debugging in Chrome, but i am looking for tool to just decode minified callstack not during debugging.

Thank you.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: Not just formatting the code, but also deobfuscated the minified javascript code to make it human readable.

Comment: You cannot have the real names back as far as I think.. Formatting is the best option

Comment: ^ Agreed, I think the mangling part is a one way process ... but tbh never really looked at the source of my minifier!